# Get value of file upload to a hidden text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value or file path from a html file upload control to a hidden input text box as soon as I select a file.

```
<input type="file" name="some_name" id="file" />
<input type="text" name="text_name" id="abc" style="display:none;" value=""/>
```

and my script looks like:

```
$('#file').live('change', function(){ alert("yes"); });
```

so I get the alert box but I would like to change the value of the hidden input field to the path of the file I select. Any help to solve this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you get an element's value with `$('#elementId').val()`, but in the case of a an `<input type="file">` you can't, because of security restrictions. There is no way to know the local file path (at least none that works consistently on all browsers).

Comment: Can I get just the filename?

Comment: Did you try `.val()`? I believe it should return the file name. Some browsers will even return the full path.

Comment: @Vinit Keep in mind that *some* browsers will return the full path, so to get just the name consistently you need something like War10ck suggested.

Answer (score 2):

To get the file path of an upload control `<input type='file'>` you can do the following:

```
var value = $('#elementID').val();
var value = value.substr(value.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

This will trim off any file path that comes before the filename. In the case of IE and Firefox the full file path and in the case of Chrome and Safari the `C:\Fake Path`.

See the associated jsfiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8ysN/)

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? I'm getting the full path on Chrome, and the file name on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work ?

```
$('#file').change(function() {
  $('#abc').val($(this).val());
});
```

I guess it doesn't: see bfavaretto answer.

Comment: It depends on the browser. But you should always be able to get the file *name* (not the full path).